# Follow sites suddenly broken SP 2013. Specific error

Tags: 2013, social, follow

'Follow' functionality has recently stopped working in our Production environment. If you notice from the error, the URL is incorrect. It is prepending the server name twice. The URL should just be `http://dcospa001-cgy/Pages/Home` not `http://dcospa001-cgyhttp://dcospa001-cgy/Pages/Home`

[image]

Any Ideas? This was working up until 2 days ago. This also occurs with our AAM / alias

Comment: Most likely there's a typo somewhere in the settings. Note that the second http// has no colon after the protocol schema name.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. But I'm not sure which setting controls this

Comment: iisreset or clear configuration cache

Comment: Thanks! I tried both, no luck. Strange because it says I'm already following the site on the second attempt

Comment: There's a Social list on your MySite that records the objects you follow.

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with fixing this error?